# Getting duplicates while converting Dictionary of list to Dictionary of Queue

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Dictonary<long, List> ids as a key, and node list as values.

**idToNode**

```
ids         nodes
10001           [1,2,3,4]
10002           [2,4,3,1]
10003           [1,3,4,2]
10004           [2,3,1,4]
10005           [4,1,2,3]
10006           [4,1,3,2]
10007           [3,2,4,1]
10008           [3,1,2,4]
10009           [4,1,3,2]
10010           [2,3,1,4]
```

Now, I am trying to convert it into Dictonary<long, Queue> node as a key, and ids list as a value. I am mapping ids with node

My code is below

```cs
public void ConvertDictionary(Dictionary<long, List<long>> jobToId)
{
    Dictionary<long, Queue<long>> idToJob = new Dictionary<long, Queue<long>>();
    foreach (long key in jobToId.Keys)
    {
        if (idToJob.ContainsKey(jobToId[key][0]))
        {
            idToJob[jobToId[key][0]].Enqueue(key);
        }
        else
        {
            idToJob.Add(jobToId[key][0], new Queue<long>(new[] { key }));
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is sometimes I am getting duplicates in my List. Please help to resolve the issue
my expected output is below:

**nodeToId**

```
node            ids
1           [10001,10003]
2           [10002,10004,10010]
3           [10007,10008]
4           [10005,10006,10009]
```

Comment: Duplicates in which list? The ids or node list?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/v3wExg

Comment: getting duplicates: In node to Id dictionary

Comment: @canton7 the problem happens with very big list

Comment: (As an aside, [this is a much clearer and more efficient way to write your method](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2RDkdJ)

Comment: @SagharFrancis If we can't see what your problem is, we can't help. Please post a [mcve] which actually reproduces your issue that we can run. Currently the code in your question functions as expected with the input in your question, so there's not much more we can say I'm afraid -- the problem is in something you haven't shared with us.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that we'll find out that there is some kind of multithreading going on.